# how to handle table td click event in salesforce lightning controller

Tags: salesforce

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#myTable td").click(function() {

```
var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() ) + 1;
var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1;    

$("#result").html( "Row_num =" + row_num + "  ,  Rolumn_num ="+ column_num );
```

});
});

Answer (score 0):

In component file you can define click event function like this

```
<td onclick="{!c.tdClickHandler}">Some text </td>
```

And in controller write the handler

```
 ({
    tdClickHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
       console.log('I am td click handler');
    }
 })
```

Comment: Hi Jogi,good to see you.But if I want to access innerHTML  of td,how do I access it?